# Erro de saída - Linguagem C

Tags: c

Boa tarde,

Atualmente estudando Linguagem C e me deparo com uma situação que tem travado no andamento dos estudos,fiz uma estrutura que recebe cadastro e endereço. O compilador não acusa erros, porém quando roda se comporta de forma estranha não permitindo receber todos os dados, a saída esperada em cada linha deveria ser:
**Nome->

Idade->

Rua->

Numero->**

Onde cada linha aponta para o dado a ser preenchido após digitar e dar enter.O erro ocorre após informar idade:
**Nome-> Jeferson

Idade-> 35

Rua-> Numero->**

Na mesma linha de **Rua->** logo em seguida aparece Numero->,tentei colocar o "\n" , mas ele pula também direto para **Numero->**.
Segue a baixo o código, e agradeço qualquer ajuda oferecida.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct endereco{
char rua[50];
int numero;
};
struct cadastro{
char nome[50];
int idade;
struct endereco ender;
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
struct cadastro c;
//Lê do teclado uma string e armazena no campo nome
printf("Nome-> ");
gets(c.nome);

//Lê do teclado um valor inteiro e armazena no campo idade
printf("Idade-> ");
scanf("%d",&c.idade);

//Lê do teclado uma string
//e armazena no campo rua da variavel ender
printf("Rua-> \n ");
gets(c.ender.rua);

//Lê do teclado um valor inteiro
//e armazena no campo numero da variavel ender
printf("Numero-> ");
scanf("%d",&c.ender.numero);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: O seu erro é a saída sem quebra de linha?

Comment: É por causa do `gets`, q ñ purga de stdin o caractere de quebra d linha

Comment: Tambéḿ tentei o fgets(), aconteceu a mesma coisa...

Comment: Tenta usar `getline`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema tem a ver com o intercalar de `gets` e `scanf`, e no caso o `gets` está a ler apenas a quebra de linha que ficou da leitura da `c.idade` deixando o texto por ler, que é apanhado pelas leituras seguintes.

No entanto, antes de começar quero deixar aqui a mensagem dada pelo compilador, que é relevante:

> main.c|18|warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

A função `gets` é perigosa e não deve ser usada! Para além disso é dificil de por a funcionar com outros tipos de leitura como o `scanf`. A alternativa mais segura seria passar para `fgets`, mas também pode resolver com `scanf` se utilizar o formatador apropriado.

### Leitura com `scanf`

Para fazer a leitura com `scanf` até ao final da linha pode utilizar `"%[^\n]"`, ou especificar o tamanho com `"%50[^\n]"`.

Com isto as suas leituras ficariam assim:

```
printf("Nome-> ");
scanf("%50[^\n]",c.nome); //ler ate ao fim da linha

printf("Idade-> ");
scanf("%d",&c.idade);

printf("Rua-> ");
scanf(" %50[^\n]",c.ender.rua);
//     ^-----este espaço consome a quebra de linha da leitura anterior

printf("Numero-> ");
scanf("%d",&c.ender.numero);
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no ideone](https://ideone.com/t4h1uC)

### Leitura com `fgets`

Para o `fgets` é preciso um pouco mais de tratamento, pois a quebra de linha é lida e armazenada na variável. Isto depois causa um efeito estranho de "Enters" a mais quando vai mostrar os seus valores.

A leitura é feita com:

```
fgets(string, tamanho, stdin);
```

A quebra de linha que ficou a mais é removida através `strcspn` que lhe dá a posição onde ela está ou o tamanho da string se não existir:

```
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0;
```

Aplicando ao seu código ficaria assim:

```
printf("Nome-> ");
fgets(c.nome, 50, stdin); //leitura com fgets
c.nome[strcspn(c.nome, "\n")] = 0; //remoção do \n

printf("Idade-> ");
scanf("%d",&c.idade);

printf("Rua-> ");
fgetc(stdin); //ler a quebra de linha da leitura anterior
fgets(c.ender.rua, 50, stdin); //leitura com fgets
c.ender.rua[strcspn(c.ender.rua, "\n")] = 0; //remoção do \n

printf("Numero-> ");
scanf("%d",&c.ender.numero);
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/KaQrkE)

Dcoumentação das funções utilizadas:

- [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)
- [fgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/)
- [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)
- [`strcspn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/)

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado pela "aula", foi o suficiente para me fazer trocar de material de estudo, pelo jeito não é nem um pouco esclarecedor.
Obrigado pelos apontamentos.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente oque estava complicando era a instrução gets, recomendo ler a explicação do colega abaixo, mas de qualquer forma aqui esta uma alternativa para seu código sem muitas alterações.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct endereco{
    char* rua[50];
    int numero;
};
typedef struct cadastro{
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    struct endereco ender;
}cadastro;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cadastro c;
    //Lê do teclado uma string e armazena no campo nome
    printf("Nome-> ");
    scanf("%s", &c.nome);

    //Lê do teclado um valor inteiro e armazena no campo idade
    printf("Idade-> ");
    scanf("%d",&c.idade);

    //Lê do teclado uma string
    //e armazena no campo rua da variavel ender

    printf("Rua-> ");
    scanf("%s", &c.ender.rua);

    //Lê do teclado um valor inteiro
    //e armazena no campo numero da variavel ender
    printf("Numero-> ");
    scanf("%d",&c.ender.numero);
/*
    printf("%s", c.nome);
    printf("\n%d", c.idade);
    printf("\n%s", c.ender.rua);
    printf("\n%d\n", c.ender.numero);
*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelos apontamentos.