# Erro com Strings em C

Tags: c

[image: A frase DIGITE A RUA só deveria aparecer logo apos ser inserido o que pede o DIGITE UM NUMERO PARA CONTATO]

A frase "*DIGITE A RUA*" só deveria aparecer logo apos ser inserido o que pede o "*DIGITE UM NUMERO PARA CONTATO*". O que deve ter acontecido?

---

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct aluno
{

char nome[50];
char nasc[10]; 
char tel[20];
char end[20]; 
char bairro[10]; 
char cidade[10];
char mae[20]; 
char pai[20];
} aluno;
      aluno CAD_ALUNO;

int main()
{

printf ("\n CADASTRO DE ALUNO:");

printf ("\n DIGITE O NOME DO ALUNO: ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.nome, 50, stdin);

printf (" DIGITE A DATA DE NASCIMENTO: ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.nasc, 10, stdin);

printf (" DIGITE UM NUMERO PARA CONTATO: ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.tel, 20, stdin);

printf (" DIGITE A RUA ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.end, 20, stdin);

printf (" DIGITE O BAIRRO ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.bairro, 10, stdin);

printf (" DIGITE A CIDADE ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.cidade, 10, stdin);

printf (" DIGITE O NOME DA MAE ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.mae, 20, stdin);

printf (" DIGITE O NOME DO PAI ");
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.pai, 20, stdin);

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso é problema de buffer, tente usar setbuf(stdin,NULL); antes dos fgets

Comment: Assim?

printf ("\n DIGITE O NOME DO ALUNO: ");
setbuf(stdin,NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.nome, 50, stdin);

Comment: Você definiu a data de nascimento com `char nasc[10];` mas escreveu `03 DE MARÇO DE 2001` que são 20 carateres, logo está incorreto e a quebra de linha não foi armazenada porque não cabia. Vale lembrar também que tamanho 20 são 19 letras pois o `\0` também tem de ser guardado. Lembro também ainda que o `fgets` guarda o `\n` já respondi a várias questões com esse problem, tal como [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304116/erro-de-sa%C3%ADda-linguagem-c/304132#304132).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema que você esta tendo aí se deve ao fato do [buffer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) do teclado não estar limpo, quando você aperta enter fica um `/n` armazenado no buffer do teclado, para acabar com esse erro basta limpar o buffer.

Para isso use a função `setbuf`, ela serve para atribuir um valor ao buffer. No caso iremos atribuir um valor nulo, então antes de cada `fgets` que você dá você adicionará o seguinte `setbuf (stdin, NULL);`, pois assim você estará dizendo que quer atribuir o valor de `NULL`, ou seja, zero ao `stdin` que é o buffer do teclado, de tal forma que seu `main` fique assim:

```
int main()
{
printf ("\n CADASTRO DE ALUNO:");

printf ("\n DIGITE O NOME DO ALUNO: "); 
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.nome, 50, stdin); 

printf (" DIGITE A DATA DE NASCIMENTO: "); 
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.nasc, 10, stdin); 

printf (" DIGITE UM NUMERO PARA 
CONTATO: "); 
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.tel, 20, stdin); 

printf (" DIGITE A RUA ");
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.end, 20, stdin); 

printf (" DIGITE O BAIRRO "); 
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.bairro, 10, stdin); 

printf (" DIGITE A CIDADE "); 
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.cidade, 10, stdin); 

printf (" DIGITE O NOME DA MAE "); 
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.mae, 20, stdin); 

printf (" DIGITE O NOME DO PAI "); 
setbuf (stdin, NULL);
fgets(CAD_ALUNO.pai, 20, stdin);

system("pause");
returne 0;
}
```

Este é o primeiro passo, além disso por boas praticas de programação tire aquela variável global que você está utilizando, e a incorpore no `main`
, pois assim você tem um código mais bonito e menos suscetível a erros.

Além disso é notável que quando você digita 03 DE ABRIL DE 2001 você esta dando um [buffer overflow](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbordamento_de_dados), pois você criou uma string, para armazenar a data, de apenas 10 caracteres, lembrando q o ultimo é reservado ao `\0` logo você terá apenas 9 caracteres disponíveis, e esta sentença, 03 DE ABRIL DE 2001, tem 20 contando com o `\0`, então você precisaria de uma string maior, ou seja, para resolver o segundo erro basta aumentar o tamanho da string para um tamanho mais adequando, eu acredito que 30 seja mais que o suficiente, após as mudanças o seu código ficara assim:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct aluno
{

    char nome[50];
    char nasc[30];
    char tel[20];
    char end[20];
    char bairro[10];
    char cidade[10];
    char mae[20];
    char pai[20];
} aluno;

int main()
{
    aluno CAD_ALUNO;

    printf ("\n CADASTRO DE ALUNO:");

    printf ("\n DIGITE O NOME DO ALUNO: ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.nome, 50, stdin);

    printf (" DIGITE A DATA DE NASCIMENTO: ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.nasc, 30, stdin);

    printf (" DIGITE UM NUMERO PARA CONTATO: ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.tel, 20, stdin);

    printf (" DIGITE A RUA ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.end, 20, stdin);

    printf (" DIGITE O BAIRRO ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.bairro, 10, stdin);

    printf (" DIGITE A CIDADE ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.cidade, 10, stdin);

    printf (" DIGITE O NOME DA MAE ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.mae, 20, stdin);

    printf (" DIGITE O NOME DO PAI ");
    setbuf (stdin, NULL);
    fgets(CAD_ALUNO.pai, 20, stdin);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Além disso também há outras maneiras de se ler uma string com espaços, eu particularmente não gosto muito do uso do `fgets` para isso, prefiro usar o `scanf`.

Para conseguir ler tudo até o `\n` com o `scanf` basta fazer o seguinte, `scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_da_string);`, assim você esta adicionando uma condição nele dizendo que é para ele ler até o `\n`, ou seja, até o final da linha, também não se esqueça de colocar o espaço entre o aspas (") e o porcento (%), pois assim você não terá erro de buffer, e não terá que ficar limpando o buffer, dessa maneira o código na `main` ficaria assim:

```
int main()
{
    aluno CAD_ALUNO;

    printf ("\n CADASTRO DE ALUNO:");

    printf ("\n DIGITE O NOME DO ALUNO: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.nome);

    printf (" DIGITE A DATA DE NASCIMENTO: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.nasc);

    printf (" DIGITE UM NUMERO PARA CONTATO: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.tel);

    printf (" DIGITE A RUA ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.end);

    printf (" DIGITE O BAIRRO ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.bairro);

    printf (" DIGITE A CIDADE ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.cidade);

    printf (" DIGITE O NOME DA MAE ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.mae);

    printf (" DIGITE O NOME DO PAI ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", CAD_ALUNO.pai);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa só perguntar, e boa sorte nos estudos de programação (^_^)/

Comment: Tudo certo Gabriel, ao pegar textos, por exemplo nome: ANGELA RIBEIRO SOUSA, até aqui tudo Ok.  Porém em DATA DE NASCIMENTO: caso eu digite : 03 DE ABRIL DE 2001 ou 03/04/2001 volta o erro da imagem a cima. Seria um problema com números?

Comment: vou editar aqui, adicionando o erro q esta dando a mais, calma ae um pouco

Comment: a edição foi feita, espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa só mandar a pergunta okay

Comment: Perfeito! Ajudou muito! Tudo certo!

Comment: `fgets` é preferivel a `scanf` pois evita buffer overflow que é algo que não acontece no código da pergunta, pois o `fgets` nunca armazena mais do que o tamanho indicado. E é algo que irá acontecer no seu se eu colocar uma string maior que qualquer um dos tamanhos definidos. No entanto, tem de ter tratamento adicional para o `\n` que fica guardado, quando fica guardado.