# Como editar dados de um Struct utilizando uma função

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, struct

Eu quero criar uma função editar que receba como parâmetro por referência o vetor de músicas. (usando ponteiros)

O usuário deve escolher o número da música e digitar novamente os dados daquela posição do vetor.

Eu criei o struct, já estou recebendo os valores e estou tocando. Mas não sei como editar os valores. Alguma pessoa para me ajudar a iniciar essa parte?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> //
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <string.h>

      struct registry_of_music  {
        char name[50];
        char artist[60];
        char url[80];
    };
    struct registry_of_music music[9];

    int main() {
    int i;
    printf("\nRegistry of Music\n\n\n");

        for(i = 0; i <= 3;i++ ){
              printf("Name of Music: ");
              fflush(stdin);
              fgets(music[i].name, 50, stdin);

              printf("Name of Artist: ");
              fflush(stdin);
              fgets(music[i].artist, 60, stdin);

              printf("URL of Internet: ");
              fflush(stdin);
              fgets(music[i].url, 80, stdin);
        }

        int op;
        do
        {
            printf("1 - Play\n");
            printf("2 - Edit\n");
            printf("3 - Exit\n");
            printf("Please enter a value:");
            scanf("%d", &op);
                    switch(op) {
                case 1: play();
                        break;
                case 2: edit();
                        break;
                case 3: printf("Bye\n");
                        break;
                default: printf("Try Again\n");
            }
        } while (op!=3);

      getch();
      return(0);
}
    void play(){
    int i;
                    for(i = 0; i <= 3;i++ ){
                      printf("Name ...........: %s", music[i].name);
                      printf("Artist .....: %s", music[i].artist);
                      printf("URL .....: %s", music[i].url);
                    }
}

    void edit(){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas observações antes de começar:

- Não coloque as funções depois do `main` sem antes dele ter as definições/assinaturas
- Se a sua estrutura já é global, pois foi declarada acima do `main`, então não precisa de a passar a nenhuma função, pois consegue aceder diretamente. Se olhar com atenção é o que acontece na função `play`.
- Não inclua mais *headers* que os estritamente necessários.
- Evite usar funções dependentes de sistema operativo como o `getch`

Posto isto, o primeiro passo é alterar o vetor para que não seja global:

```
int main() {
    struct registry_of_music music[9];
    ...
```

Que agora lhe dará erro de compilação na função `play`. Para corrigir, basta alterar a função para receber o vetor tal como pretende fazer na função `editar`:

```
void play(struct registry_of_music *music /*<--aqui*/) {
    //código da função
}
```

E agora quando chama a função, passa o endereço do vetor que é apenas `music`:

```
int main() {
    ...
        switch(op) {
        case 1:
            play(music);
//                  ^---
            break;
```

Agora para o editar é idêntico, mas passando a posição da musica a alterar:

```
case 2:
    printf("Please enter the position of the music to edit:");
    int edit_index;
    scanf("%d", &edit_index);
    edit(music, edit_index);
    //              ^----
    break;
```

E a função ficaria assim:

```
void edit(struct registry_of_music *music, int index) {
    printf("Editing music %s", music[index].name);
    printf("New Name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(music[index].name, 50, stdin);

    printf("New Artist: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(music[index].artist, 60, stdin);

    printf("New URL: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(music[index].url, 80, stdin);
}
```

Como nota final, as leituras que está a fazer com `fgets` deixam o `\n` dentro das strings, que é o motivo pelo qual não tem de o fazer manualmente. Já respondi sobre como contornar isso noutras perguntas, tal como [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304116/erro-de-sa%C3%ADda-linguagem-c/304132#304132).

Código com todas as alterações para referência:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct registry_of_music  {
    char name[50];
    char artist[60];
    char url[80];
};

void play(struct registry_of_music *music) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++ ) {
        printf("Name ...........: %s", music[i].name);
        printf("Artist .....: %s", music[i].artist);
        printf("URL .....: %s", music[i].url);
    }
}

void edit(struct registry_of_music *music, int index) {
    printf("Editing music %s", music[index].name);
    printf("New Name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(music[index].name, 50, stdin);

    printf("New Artist: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(music[index].artist, 60, stdin);

    printf("New URL: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(music[index].url, 80, stdin);
}

int main() {
    struct registry_of_music music[9];
    int i;
    printf("\nRegistry of Music\n\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++ ) {
        printf("Name of Music: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(music[i].name, 50, stdin);

        printf("Name of Artist: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(music[i].artist, 60, stdin);

        printf("URL of Internet: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(music[i].url, 80, stdin);
    }

    int op;
    do {
        printf("1 - Play\n");
        printf("2 - Edit\n");
        printf("3 - Exit\n");
        printf("Please enter a value:");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch(op) {
        case 1:
            play(music);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Please enter the position of the music to edit:");
            int edit_index;
            scanf("%d", &edit_index);
            edit(music, edit_index);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Bye\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Try Again\n");
        }
    } while (op!=3);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Sua explicação foi perfeita. Entendi todos os passos de forma sucinta. Muito obrigado por esse seu tempo e por sua explicação, me ajudou demais.

Comment: @spw Sem problema. Estamos cá para ajudar :)