# Problema com fgets em C

Tags: c

Esse é o trecho do meu código com o problema:

```
int main (void) {

    int n_sentencas, n_perguntas;

    scanf("%d %d", &n_sentencas, &n_perguntas);
    fflush(stdin);

    char** sentenca; // ponteiro para matriz que armazena as sentencas
    sentenca = malloc(n_sentencas * sizeof(char*)); // alocacao das linhas da matriz que vao representar uma sentenca cada
    char** pergunta; // ponteiro para matriz que armazena as perguntas
    pergunta = malloc(n_perguntas * sizeof(char*)); // alocacao das linhas da matriz que vao representar uma pergunta cada


    for (int i = 0; i <= n_sentencas; i++) { // for que le as sentencas
        sentenca[i] = malloc(400 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(sentenca[i], 400, stdin);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n_perguntas; i++) { // for que le as perguntas
        pergunta[i] = malloc(400 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(pergunta[i], 400, stdin);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n_sentencas; i++) { // for que imprime as sentencas
        printf("sentenca %d: \n", i+1);
        printf("%s\n", sentenca[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n_perguntas; i++) { // for que imprime as perguntas
        printf("pergunta %d: \n", i+1);
        printf("%s\n", pergunta[i]);
    }
```

O problema que ocorre é que a primeira linha da matriz `sentenca` é sempre ignorada, como no exemplo abaixo:

Entrada:

```
3 2
bom
dia
amigos
como vao voces?
(nessa linha deveria ter uma quinta entrada, mas o programa imprime os valores apenas 
com 4 strings na entrada, ao invés de 5)
```

Então a saída fica o seguinte:

```
sentenca 1:


sentenca 2:
bom

sentenca 3:
dia

pergunta 1:
amigos

pergunta 2:
como vao voces?
```

Gostaria de saber como resolver isso.

Comment: O problema e solução é o mesmo que eu falo [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304116/erro-de-sa%C3%ADda-linguagem-c/304132#304132). No seu caso a solução é consumir o `\n` com `fgetc(stdin)` a seguir ao primeiro `scanf`. Embora `fflush(stdin);` tente fazer o mesmo, isso só irá funcionar em algumas implementações, e tipicamente em linux não funciona.

Comment: @Isac Eu tentei usar ```fflush``` pra solucionar esse problema e não funcionou, aí eu acabei tendo que perguntar aqui, já que eu não conhecia o ```fgetc```. Aliás, que ```\n``` é esse?

Comment: É o enter que você coloca para inserir os valores, e que o `scanf` não consumiu e acaba a ser a unica coisa que o primeiro `fgets` lê

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vejamos

Tomará *duas ações* para resolver o problema. A *segunda ação* a ser tomada possui duas alternativas, ficando a teu critério qual escolher. Particularmente, prefiro o *segundo caso*.

---

### Primeira ação

Troca o trecho abaixo:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n_sentencas; i++) { // for que le as sentencas
```

... Por este:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_sentencas; i++) { // for que le as sentencas
```

O operador `<=` não fazia o programa ler `n_sentencas` mas sim ler `n_sentencas+1`. Trocar o operador `<=` pelo operador `<` resolve parte do problema.

Explicando: quando da leitura das perguntas, a primeira delas era lida em um trecho da memória que não compreende a memória reservada mas que era adjacente à memória da última das sentenças.

### Segunda ação

**CASO 1** - Troca o trecho abaixo:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

... Por:

```
setbuf(stdin, NULL);
```

[`setbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setbuf/) descartará o buffer já que, na prática, não vai existir *buffer* para o `stdin`. O *buffer* é o problema por armazenar o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, representado na forma de pulo de linha `\n`. Assim, sem *buffer*, o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que pressionastes para a entrada de dados se concretizar será descartado.

Caso vier a precisar do *buffer*, crie um *buffer* na seção de código que desejar:

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ];
setbuf(stdin, buffer);
```

**CASO 2** - Alternativamente ao *caso 1*, apague:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

... E troque:

```
scanf("%d %d", &n_sentencas, &n_perguntas);
```

... Por:

```
scanf("%d %d%*c", &n_sentencas, &n_perguntas);
```

O `*` em `%*c` [descartará o próximo dado do tipo escolhido](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#parameters) (*neste caso, `c` de caractere*). Não será, portanto, escrito ou mesmo armazenado no *buffer* qualquer caractere. Neste caso, o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> não será armazenado ou escrito.

Só tome cuidado para não dar um ou mais espaços aleatórios ou mesmo outros caracteres. Cada caractere é um `%*c` a mais necessário que você não vai por pois é acidente de percurso. Assim, o *caso 1* é mais eficiente se não for entrada automática de dados por conta de erros do usuário do programa.